# A comparison between <shy>, <embarrassed> and <ashamed>

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Dictionaries' definitions don't seem to be quite distinguishing that I can choose between these three words and use them properly. I wonder if you could have a look on my scenario and let me know which one is correct:

**Example**

> A) Why you don't express your emotions to me? (Says a girl to her boyfriend.) 
>   B) You're right. But telling the truth, (I have always been / I have always felt)............................. 
>   1) **shy of telling you** that I love you. 
>   2) **shy to tell you** that I love you. 
>   3) **embarrassed of telling you** that I love you. 
>   4) **embarrassed to tell you** that I love you. 
>   5) **ashamed of telling you** that I love you. 
>   6) **ashamed to tell you** that I love you.

I wonder which words can be used in this sense. To me, they all work, but as far as I'm concerned the word "**ashamed**" can be used in a little bit **more serious** sutuations and this is why examples with "ashamed" seem to be less appropriate in this case.

Comment: None of these fits quite right, in my opinion.  Better: *To tell you the truth, I've never been comfortable expressing my feelings in words.*

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be ashamed **to tell you** that I love you unless there was a reason I thought it morally wrong to love you.

I wouldn't be embarrassed **to tell you** that I love you unless I thought loving you isn't what society expects of me.

I would be shy **to tell you** I love you if I felt awkward telling you.

"*of telling you*" doesn't sound quite right to my ear, but I don't know why.

Comment: I am not an expert on the English language and have no formal qualifications in English. I offer my advice only as a native British English speaker. I believe the advice of an untrained English speaker can sometimes be beneficial.

Comment: Perhaps he stopped just "shy of telling" her that he loved her.